# rotate mysql select

Tags: mysql, select

How can I rotate select by a given number.

I want to rotate select items in each visit of a visitor.

On first visit, the newest item is displayed.

On second visit, the second newest come first and the newest goes to the last page, last item.

On third visit, the third come first and the second goes to last page, last item just after newest.

I capture the visit count with a cookie on the first page.

But how can I select circularly?

Comment: Uhm, the question is not clear, at least for me

Comment: on each visit, i want my items rotate one to the top. so visitor always see different item on each visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Either you load the complete resultset into an array and output appropriately, or
2. you issue two queries:

   - one for `n` till the end (`LIMIT n+1, 100000000` will do in most cases) and
   - one for 1 till n (`LIMIT n`).

e.g. this way:

```
(SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY whatever LIMIT $n+1, 1000000) UNION ALL
(SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY whatever LIMIT $n)
```

with `$n` being the visit count excluding the current visit.

EDIT: As @ypercube pointed out, not only the UNION ALL is necessary, but the order of the result COULD be mixed up anyway. So it is better to issue two queries - which should be no problem, as the additional complexity in code is just marginal if you use a loop.

Comment: Can it be done through a union? would you please suggest a query which do the job.

Comment: Yes, a union would work perfectly. A query would have provided by yourseld, because only you know the structure of the tables, but principially it could be done the way I point out in my edit.

Comment: A `UNION` query without an `ORDER BY` means that the result set will be ordered however the database chooses, without any specific order.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: And using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` or `WHERE` is usually pointless.

Comment: `ORDER BY`: yes. `WHERE`: not necessarily. The exact query is up to the original poster; but principially, if he wants to display everything there is no need for a `WHERE`, as long as the data set is small enough. I don't know what he wants to display, but I'm sure he knows.

Comment: @glglgl: I meant that usually a query with `LIMIT` has also **either** `ORDER BY` **or** `WHERE` (or both). In this case, he probably needs the first.

Comment: @glglgl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2473/discussion-between-ypercube-and-glglgl)

Comment: (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT $shift, 1000) UNION
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT $shift) LIMIT $page_offset, $limit

Comment: It did the job! ;) You must add the outer limit to your query. Because it was what I was asking for.

Comment: Actually it seems that shift + 1 is right. but this is working right?